# Get thread handle from memory address

Tags: multithreading, delphi, debugging, exception

My multithreaded delphi application has a VEH exception handler. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681420(v=vs.85).aspx) i can get memory address, exception type etc when triggered but can't get thread information.

is it possible to get thread id from memory address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to get thread ID from a memory address?

If by memory address you mean address of code then the answer is no. Multiple threads can be simultaneously executing at the same address.

I see no evidence that these exception handlers are called in a thread other than the one which raised the exception.